# Call js function and send some data when click an option from dropdown in Datatable row

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm looking for call a js function after click on my dropdown list. The code works, when I click it, it call myFunction. My problem is I need to add the datatable row into myFunction as a parameter.

My error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: meta`

I'm noob with javascript and html languages.

```
<script>
function myFunction(selectObject, row) {
    var value = selectObject.value; 
    alert("Actualización Status: " + value + row);
}
</script>

<script>
    var json={{ posts_list | safe }};
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#posts_table').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
            ],
            "scrollX": true,
            data: json.data,
            columns:[
                {defaultContent: ""},
                {data: "_id"},
                {
                    "data": "status",
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                        if (data == 'no_denunciado') {
                            data = '<select id="status" onchange="myFunction(this, meta.row)">' +
                            '<option value="no_denunciado">' + data + '</option>' +
                            '<option value="nuevo">Nuevo</option>' +
                            '<option value="en_gestion">En Gestion</option>' +
                            '<option value="baja_edenor">Baja</option>' +
                            '</select>';
                        }
```

Comment: `meta` is an argument to the `render` function. By the time `myFunction` is called, it's out of scope and JavaScript has no idea what you're talking about. I suggest adding elements using DOM methods (i.e., `createElement`) and using `addEventListener` to include the enclosed variable as needed. There may be something easier in DataTables though.

Comment: chang select id="status" onchange="myFunction(this, meta.row)"> to select id="status" onchange="myFunction(this,\''+meta.row+'\')">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meta.row is being used out of scope of the function you need to put in the data not the variable meta.data as that will fall out of scope like so.

change

```
data = '<select id="status" onchange="myFunction(this, meta.row)>'
```

to

```
data = '<select id="status" onchange="myFunction(this, \''+meta.row+'\')">'
```

EDIT from the chat I see that you want to string an object I wrote a quick function

```
function ObjectToString(myObject){
var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
var returnedString="";
keys.forEach(key=>{returnedString+="["+key+":"+myObject[key]+"]";});
return returnedString;
}
```

Comment: It's works!!! Is there any way to get the row data? Because now my alert shows me 0 or 1 (the index)

Comment: the data is in the option so just get the innerhtml

Comment: I mean the complete row data, not only the option. I mean, now if I send row instead of meta.row in params I have [Object object]. Is there any way to get the same but in json format?

Comment: you can create an array and store away meta in an array connected to the row number [row1:meta] and so on then you can figure out what part of the array you need from the row number

Comment: the array must be outside the function

Comment: My apologies if I'm not clear. If I do `console.log(row)` in myFunction I have `[Object object]`. How can I see the row data instead of `[Object object]`

Comment: I added a junction to string an object :) You can change the way it is done if you don't like the format